# Are gravitational forces unequal between two masses?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

$$F=G\frac{M_1\cdot M_2}{d^2}$$

Is the gravitation force of $M_1$ to $M_2$ unequal to force of $M_2$ to $M_1$?

For Sun and Mercury; Sun has huge mass so his force on Mercury is high. Mercury also has mass, tiny mass, with that tiny mass it is pulling Sun. From this the forces don't seem equal. Is gravitational force mutual, or independent?

Comment: You can easily calculate F21, how does it compare with F12?

Comment: Why do you think the forces would be unequal?

Comment: @BobD For Sun and Mercury; Sun has huge mass so his force on Mercury is high. Mercury also has mass, tiny mass, with that tiny mass it is pulling Sun. From this the forces don't seem equal. Is gravitational force mutual, or independent?

Comment: But the force is proportional to the product of the two masses. I hope it's obvious that $M_1\cdot M_2 = M_2\cdot M_1$

Comment: @Majoris The force that the Sun exerts on Mercury is equal and opposite to the force Mercury exerts on the Sun, per Newton's 3rd law. But since the mass of Mercury is so much less than the mass of the Sun the effect of the force causes Mercury to orbit around the sun whereas the effect on the Sun is so small that it appears stationary  (though actually it’s not).

Comment: An example closer to home. The Earth exerts a force of about 1.5 N on a 0.15 kg baseball. If dropped it experiences an acceleration of about 9.8 m/s$^2$ towards the Earth. The baseball exerts the same 1.5 N on the Earth causing the Earth to accelerate up towards the baseball. But the mass of the Earth is so much greater than the ball, its acceleration is only on the order of 10$^{-24}$m/s$^2$, making it effectively appear stationary.

Comment: Given the answers you have received, do you see now that the gravitation force of M1 on M2 and M2 on M1 have the same magnitude? If not, what are your remaining doubts?

Comment: @BobD I am still not convinced. Since gravity is experienced from bending of the space-time, Sun and Mercury must be stretching it in unequally. Sure, Newton's equation presents these combined as a force magnitude between point masses.

Answer (score 2):

No the forces must follow the third Newton law so $ |F_{1 \rightarrow 2}| = |F_{2 \rightarrow 1}|$

Answer (score 1):

The forces are exactly equal to each other but opposite in directions as per Newton's Third Law, but the reason we might see one body move more than the other body is another matter entirely, a topic related to the inertias of the bodies involved.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said, the forces must be equal and opposite based Newton's 3rd law. It is the acceleration of each mass that will not be equal unless the masses are equal. The magnitude of the acceleration of each is based on applying Newton's 2nd law to each mass individually, or

$$a_{1}=\frac{F}{M_1}$$

$$a_{2}=\frac{F}{M_2}$$

> For Sun and Mercury; Sun has huge mass so his force on Mercury is
> high. Mercury also has mass, tiny mass, with that tiny mass it is
> pulling Sun. From this the forces don't seem equal. Is gravitational
> force mutual, or independent?

Newton's universal law of gravitation can be stated, in conjunction with the equation, as follows:

"any particle of matter in the universe attracts any other with a force varying directly as the product of the masses and inversely as the square of the distance between them" (Britannica.com)

Note is says that the particles attract *each other* with *a force*, not that each particle attracts the other with a different force. Moreover, this force is proportional to the produce of the masses of the particle, not proportional to the mass of each product.

So the force the Sun exerts on Mercury is equal in magnitude to the force Mercury exerts on the Sun, consistent with Newton's third law. Or, as you put it, the force of gravity is "mutual", not "independent".

What is independent is the acceleration that each particle experiences as a result of the same force. That is governed by Newton's 2nd law, as previously discussed. This makes the acceleration of the Sun due to the force exerted by Mercury infinitesimal compared to the acceleration of Mercury due to the force of the Sun. In the case of orbiting bodies the acceleration is centripetal acceleration.

Although in actuality Mercury and the Sun orbit each other, the point about which they orbit each other (known as the "barycenter") is the center of mass (COM) of the two bodies. Given that the mass of the Sun is approximately 6 million times that of Mercury, the COM is essentially the center of the Sun. So it only appears that Mercury orbits the Sun. On the other hand, in the case of Jupiter, the COM is just outside the Sun's surface. See

https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/barycenter/en/

Hope this helps.